# In a 52 deck card, you draw 4 cards without replacement, what are the odds of picking exactly 2 different suits and a 5?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

In a standard 52 card deck, what are the odds of picking exactly:

1. 2 Different suit
2. a 5

**Picking two different suits:** (52/52) * (39/51)

**Picking a 5:** (1/52)

0.76 * 0.019 = 0.014

What to do with the remaining card?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to joriki's approach, let's count the number of $4$-card hands with exactly two suits and at least one $5$ as

$${4\choose2}{24\choose2}+{4\choose1}{3\choose1}\left[{24\choose3}-{12\choose3}\right]=23{,}304$$

The first part, ${4\choose2}{24\choose2}$, counts the number of hands with two $5$s: First pick the two $5$s, then pick two more cards from the remaining $24$ cards in the chosen two $5$s' suits. The second part counts the number of hands with just one $5$: First pick a $5$, then pick a second suit, then choose $3$ cards from the $24$ non-$5$s in those two suits, but don't count the choices where all $3$ cards come from the remaining $12$ cards in the suit with the chosen $5$.

Comment: $+1$ – one fewer addition, two fewer binomial coefficients, and no complicated factors of $3$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

I gather from your own attempts that by “odds” you don’t actually mean the [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) but the [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability).

There are $\binom42$ ways to choose two different suits, and $\binom{26}4$ ways to choose the $4$ cards from those two suits, so the value to start out with for this probability is

$$
\frac{\binom42\binom{26}4}{\binom{52}4}\;.
$$

But that also counts selections from a single suit $3$ times, so we have to subtract those $3$ times. And it counts selections without a $5$, so we have to subtract those. But that subtracts each selection from a single suit without a $5$ three times, and we’d already subtracted those, so we have to add those back in three times. If we put that all together, the desired probability comes out as

$$
\frac{\binom42\binom{26}4-3\cdot\binom41\binom{13}4-\binom42\binom{24}4+3\cdot\binom41\binom{12}4}{\binom{52}4}=\frac{23304}{270725}\approx0.086\;.
$$

Comment: when subtracting those 3 times (to remove selections from a single suit 3 times) also prevents the occurence of selecting a single suit 4 times? sorry im a bit confused with the second part of your answer

Comment: By "counts selections from a single suit $3$ times", I don't mean "counts selections of $3$ cards from a single suit". By "selection" I always mean a selection of $4$ cards. "$3$ times" refers to the fact that there are $3$ pairs of suits in which the single suit occurs, so each selection of $4$ cards from a single suit is counted $3$ times, once for each of those pairs. For instance, $4$ hearts are counted as $4$ cards that are all either hearts or diamonds, as $4$ cards that are all either hearts or clubs, and as $4$ cards that are all either hearts or spades.